# Change Color of listbox items based on conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

i have a list box that checks the status of list of printers by pinging to that ip, if the connection times out i would like for it to show up in "red" how can i do this, i am using the following code:

```
Ping ipping = new Ping();
PingReply replyab01 = ipping.Send(abilene01, 1000);
if (replyab01 != null)
{
     ZplPrinterStatus.Items.Add("Abilene Primary(01) Printer Status:"+ replyab01.Status);
}
else
{
     ZplPrinterStatus.Items.Add("Abilene Primary(01) Printer Status:" + "Error Printer Time out");
     // ZplDownSatus.Visible = true;
}
```

please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to change the color server-side or do it in the client?
If your just wanted to change it from ASP.NET/Server side, then just create a new list item and give it a style attribute of color:red before adding it to the listbox-

```
Ping ipping = new Ping();
PingReply replyab01 = ipping.Send(abilene01, 1000);
if (replyab01 != null)
{
    (if replyab01.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        ZplPrinterStatus.Items.Add("Abilene Primary(01) Printer Status:" + replyab01.Status);
    }
}
else
{
    ListItem item = new ListItem("Abilene Primary(01) Printer Status:" + "Error Printer Time out");
    item.Attributes["style"] = "color:red;";
    ZplPrinterStatus.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Items.Add doesn't have a signature that accepts a color.  What I gave you should work.  What exactly is going on?  An exception or its not updating the color?

Comment: That did not work mate, any other suggestions?? its not updating the color. the items that timed out are still black

Comment: @BeastMode that should work.  Are you doing anything else in the code?  Are there any css classes that are 'overwriting'  the change?

Comment: @Ageonix the above code worked for me the only issue was that else part of the code was never hit in debug because replyab01 is always not null so if only goes through the if condition, so i changed it to check against the ping reply status and that fixed the issue.